# Extract numbers from string and multiply each digit oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

string type column contains data like String1='1* 2 * 3 * 4 *5.....*N'

i need result in integer data type like prod=1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * 5.....*N

Ex1: if string1='1 * 2' then prod=1 *2=2
Ex2: if string2='1 * 2 * 3' then prod=1 *2 *3=6

Comment: this should be done in Oracle SQL/PlSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xmlquery` can do this easily:

```
select xmlcast(xmlquery('1*2*3*4' returning content) as number) as result
from   dual
;


RESULT
------
    24
```

The string doesn't have to be hard-coded - it can be a column name, or any other string expression that returns a valid arithmetic expression. (Note that if you have division, you would need to replace `/` with  `div` - for example by using the `replace` function.)

Comment: Thanks its working.Could you please provide more information for xmlquery details

Comment: `xmlquery` is a huge topic, it's not possible to cover it in comments to a single answer here. If you are not familiar with XML, you have a choice... is it worth your time learning about it? The answer is not easy - there are many benefits, but the learning time will be considerable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using [*Native Dynamic SQL*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-7E2F596F-9CA3-4DC8-8333-0C117962DB73) (NDS)

```sql
declare
  L_RESULT number;
  L_STR    varchar2(5);
begin
  L_STR := '1*2*3';
  execute immediate 'select ' || L_STR || ' from dual'
    into L_RESULT;
  dbms_output.put_line(to_char(L_RESULT));
end;
```